# How can i save data from multipart/form-data in servlet and save this data to db?

Tags: android, servlets

```
public void saveData(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {
        boolean checkMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        System.out.println(checkMultiPart);
        //fin = request.getInputStream();
        Part part = request.getPart("pic");
        fin = part.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(fin);
        writer = response.getWriter();
        if(fin != null){
            fin.read();
            System.out.println("Inside Function");
            query = "INSERT INTO SAVEPIC(picID,PIC) VALUES (picIncVal.nextval,?)";
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            insertStatement.setBinaryStream(1, fin, fin.available());
            row = insertStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
            System.out.println("Save To Data Base");
        }
        if (row > 0)
            writer.print("SUCCESS");
        else
            writer.print("FAILED");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        writer.print("Pic Value is Null");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(fin != null)
                fin.close();
            if(writer != null)
                writer.close();
            if (connection != null) {
                insertStatement.close();
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**I want to store image which i am sending from android in multipart/form-data. Can any one give me suggestions how can i do it.**

By this code only some bits are storing into the db, Not whole image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using setBlob() method of PreparedStatement.

Comment: but problem with this code is that i am getting only few bits.i am using postman rest client i.e chrome extension to upload the image

Comment: In that case just to confirm that issue is not with the rest cilent, upload image by using an HTML Form with enctype attribute.

Comment: `<form action="/TestServer/SavePicServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select Image to upload <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
   <br/>
   <button type="submit">Uplaod</button>
  </form>`
but it is showing false when we executed `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)` on servlet .

Comment: If you use Chrome to open the HTML page with the form, you'll be able to see the multipart request in the network tab. If you can see it then it means Form has done it's job. If you're not able to get the file parameter may be it's an issue with the attribute name, file type input should have the name 'pic' as used in the request.getPart('pic').